# Best efficient way to split this pattern

Tags: java, regex, split, stringtokenizer

I have a file which includes thousands of lines like this:

```
node: { title: "0" label: "sub_401000" color: 76 textcolor: 73 bordercolor: black }
```

What I need is to extract the title value and label value. For example in the line above. I need to extract 0 and sub_401000. I can split them but it takes a lot of time. 
I want to know what would be the most efficient way to do this process?

Comment: As an aside, whoever wrote this file could have saved valid json instead of this, which would have made everything simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do (Note I assumed there to be one space between title: and quotes.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "node: { title: \"0\" label: \"sub_401000\" color: 76 textcolor: 73 bordercolor: black }";
        //String regex = ".*title: \"(.*)\".*label: \"(.*)\""; better regex below suggested by pschemo
        String regex = "title: \"([^\"]*)\".*label: \"([^\"]*)\"";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if(m.find())
        {
            String title = m.group(1);
            String label = m.group(2);
            System.out.println(title);
            System.out.println(label);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

0

sub_401000

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it is faster than my solution :)

Comment: You should avoid `\"(.*)\"` since `*` is greedy and causes backtracking. Use `\"([^\"]*)\"` instead.

Comment: Also there is no need for `.*` at start of regex since you are using `m.find()` method.

Comment: Explain a bit further "is greedy and causes backtracking" please?

Comment: `\"(.*)\"` since `.` can match any character (except line separators) regex `".*"`  will match `\"0\" label: \"sub_401000\"` since it starts and ends with `"`, but then since regex engine will not be able to match `label: ` anywhere else it will need to reduce previously matched part to check if it wasn't *too-greedy*. Take a look at this example: `"foo 'a' bar 'b' baz 'c'".replaceAll("'.*'","X")` will result in `foo X`. Now if you change it to `"foo 'a' bar 'b' baz 'c'".replaceAll("'.*' baz","X baz")` you will get `foo X baz 'c'`.

Comment: For more info read http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html  "Watch Out for The Greediness!" and especially "Looking Inside The Regex Engine" part.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this regex and compile it if possible since it will be used repetitively. (Note: it is meant for capturing matches using the parenthesis)

```
 (\w+): "*(\w*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/efnEk8FYyRGxpo7Q)